# CSRF и XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, csrf

XMLHttpRequest использует Same Origin Policy (http://xmlhttprequest.ru/#security) То есть со страницы на `site.com` нельзя сделать XMLHttpRequest-запрос на `another.com`. Является ли это достаточной защитой от CSRF? Значит ли это, что CSRF посредством XMLHttpRequest невозможен?

Прочитал статью https://learn.javascript.ru/csrf и сложилось ощущение, что автор не прочитал спецификацию XMLHttpRequest, и из-за этого стал делать неправильные выводы.

Answer (score 0):

**CSRF** работает при обычных (не XMLHttpRequest) запросах. Вы можете создать на своем сайте форму и отправлять с нее результаты на другой сайт.

Вот от таких атак и защищает **CSRF-токен**.

К тому же **CORS** работает на стороне браузера и если пользователь использует "плохой" браузер, то даже **CORS** не будет работать.

Comment: Это всё понятно. Интересовал CSRF именно с XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: тогда не понятно на основе чего у вас: *и сложилось ощущение, что автор не прочитал спецификацию XMLHttpRequest*?